# Android exception when using a kotlin library in java code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library

I am importing the below library from github

https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

which is a kotlin library that I want to use in my java code. When I call `calendar.setup(...);` as mentioned in the doc, I get the below strange error, while commenting out this line of code the error disappears and app runs.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2155)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1155)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.utils.ExtensionsKt.inflate(Extensions.kt:12)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.utils.ExtensionsKt.inflate$default(Extensions.kt:11)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.DayHolder.inflateDayView(DayHolder.kt:28)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.WeekHolder.inflateWeekView(WeekHolder.kt:24)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.MonthViewHolder.<init>(MonthViewHolder.kt:32)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.CalendarAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CalendarAdapter.kt:122)
        at com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.CalendarAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CalendarAdapter.kt:27)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7072)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Does this have to do with using kotlin library in java. (maybe I need to add some other kotlin dependencies?)

Comment: It seems that you are not passing a correct resource id to that library for some attribute. Library probably defaults to `0` but does not handle the case when resource id is 0. In android, having resource id 0 is bad and should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help. Anyway, I received the same error before but not because of the `calendar.setup(...)` thing. It is because i was unconsciously trying to set an integer to my calendar `DayView` container's `TextView`, and after converting the integer to string it works fine.